# How to show labels containing currency symbols in Blogger blog post?

Tags: xml, label, blogger

How to show labels containing currency symbols (i:e products price such as 18$, 19£) in Blogger blog post?

```
<div class='item_price'>
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
<b:if cond='data:label.name == "$"&&"£"'>
<span class='price'><data:label.name/></span>
</b:if>
</b:loop>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `contains` or `in`

**With contains**

```
<div class='item_price'>
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
<b:if cond='data:label.name contains "$" or data:label.name contains "£"'>
<span class='price'><data:label.name/></span>
</b:if>
</b:loop>
</div>
```

**With in**

```
<div class='item_price'>
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
<b:if cond='"$" in data:label.name or "£" in data:label.name'>
<span class='price'><data:label.name/></span>
</b:if>
</b:loop>
</div>
```